# Do quantiles of quantiles converge to quantiles?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, probability-limit-theorems

Is there any truth to the statement "the median of medians converges to the true median?".

While it's false that the median of medians is the median, is there a way to make this true asymptotically? I'm happy to take on regularity conditions on the underlying distribution (like continuous density function, etc).

More precisely, this is my setup. I have iid random samples $x_{i,j}$ of some random variable $X$.

For each $i$, I can take the median over $j$.

$$ m_i(n) := \text{median}(x_{i,j} | j \leq n) $$

And then take the median over those

$$ m(k,n) := \text{median}(m_i(n)| i \leq k) $$

Is it true that

$$ \lim_{k,n \to \infty} m(k,n) = \text{the actual median of } X $$

under some conditions on $X$?

And same question where median is replaced by other quantiles of $X$.

(though a counterexample with a non-super-weird $X$ (say continuous with finite mean and variance) would make me even happier)

---

I found this reference from another question, [https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/papers/unpublished/meanmed.pdf](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etom/papers/unpublished/meanmed.pdf)

where it claims that the distribution of sample quantiles is asymptotically normal. So I guess the correct statement is that "average of quantile converges to quantile". IIUC, a counterexample to "quantile of quantile converges to quantile" would be greatly appreciated then!

Comment: If the distribution of sample quantiles is asymptotically normal, then, asymptotically, it has equal mean and median. Hence the statement holds for the median.

Comment: @HeiniHøgnason Thanks.